# What are the main disadvantages of building streaming applications with a simple client server architecture?

Tags: node.js, streaming, flink-streaming, stream-processing

I have no experience with building streaming applications - and having mostly worked on building small scale (from a usage/load perspective) applications, never had a proper "brush" with them in production. So as an outsider, I am curious to know what challenges led to the evolution of dedicated streaming systems like Flink, Kafka, or their predecessors.

Books that cover these topics that I've encountered, assume the reader knows *why* the model is the Right Way to build these systems. But if I were to embark on a foolish endeavour to build a highly scalable data ingestion stream (say, for a large number of servers that are all outputting huge amounts of Apache logs and system metrics) using something like Node.js, what sort of walls would I run into that would make me wish for a good streaming system?

Comment: A mod is likely going to close this question because it's not a fit for SO (off topic or something like that). SO questions should be more specific and code-centric, not about meta software architecture questions. There are other stack exchange sites for that, like software engineering stack exchange and the like.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up. I'll not create a clone on SWEng site until this one gets closed then, just in case folks misinterpret it again as spam.. (but thank you again for warning the close hammer is probably coming)

Comment: Exactly-once end-to-end at scale.